# Connect to VPN without changing IP

Tags: networking, 3g, vpn, ip-address

On my windows 7 laptop, when I connect to my work VPN, my IP stays the same as it was before connecting to the VPN.

However, on my android phone, when I connect to my university's VPN, my IP is different than the one provided by my carrier (I'm using a 3g connection by the way) .

Is there any way I can connect to my university's VPN and keep my carrier's IP address?

If more info is needed, let me know and I'll do my best to provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: What kind of VPN is it? Are you using a third-party client on either instance (Windows or Android), and if so, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your IP address and using a VPN is the complete opposite of what VPNs are invented for. VPNs make you part of a network through a tunnel connection so that your phone is on the same level as locally connected devices.
This means your IP address will be the one of the VPN. If you don't like this, then you should not use a VPN.
Also check your IP on your laptop. It is probably not the one you used to connect to the VPN.
One possible explanation could also be that your work's VPN transfers your IP address as HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR so the server knows you are using that server as a proxy server. This appears not to be configured in your university's VPN and therefore your IP address is not sent to the destination server, which is totally working by design.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've looked into this and it seems the client I'm using to connect to my work's VPN uses [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling), which means (if I understood correctly) only traffic destined for the local network is sent through the tunnel - internet traffic is not. This explains why whatismyip.com was giving me my ISP's IP.